# Homeomorphism between a piece of sphere and a convex set on a Banach space.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, geometric-functional-analysis

Let $(X,|\cdot|)$ be a real Banach space and $K\subseteq X$ a *closed cone*, that is, $K$ is a nonempty closed subset of $X$ satisfying: (*a*) $0\in K$; (*b*) $x+y\in K$ whenever $x,y\in K$; (*c*) $tx\in K$ whenever $t>0$ and $x\in K$; (*d*) if $x\in K\setminus\{0\}$ then $-x\notin K$. Denote $K_1=\{x\in K : |x|=1\}$.

> **Question:** Is it true that there exist a closed (affine) subspace $Y\subseteq X$ and a convex set $C\subseteq Y$ such that $K_1$ is homeomorphic to $C$?

I'm reading the paper "On Krasnoselskii’s Cone Fixed Point Theorem" by Kwong [2008] and the author simply say it's easily seeing, so I guess it's just something I'm not looking at in the right way. In fact, it's pretty intuitive, and I'm looking for a formal proof. Thanks in advance.

*My thoughts:* It's easy to see that $K$ is necessarily convex. Then the closed convex hull of $K_1$, $\operatorname{conv}(K_1)$, is contained in $K$. I've tried to prove that $0$ does not belong to $\operatorname{conv}(K_1)$ in order to use the Hahn Banach Separation Theorem to get a functional $\phi\in X^*$ and $\alpha>0$ such that $\phi(x)>\alpha$ for every $x\in\operatorname{conv}(K_1)$. This would give me an affine subspace $A=\{x\in X : \phi(x)=\alpha\}$ which separates $K_1$ and $\{0\}$. Next, I would like to define $C=A\cap K$ and the homeomorphism I'm looking for could be a radial projection or something similar.

There are very steps that seem unclear to me in this argument, I'd appreciate any comments, hints or improvements.

Comment: Is it necessary to define $Y$? Wouldn't finding a convex set $C \subseteq X$ be the same sthing?

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets It's not necessary. I've included it in my question hoping that my argument is a right one

Comment: It can happen that $0 \in \overline{\operatorname{conv}}(K_1)$. Take $X= \ell_\infty$ and $K = \{x \in X; \; \forall n: x_n \geq 0\}$. Then $e_n \in K_1$ for all $n$ and hence $\sum_{i=1}^k k^{-1} e_i \in \operatorname{conv}(K_1)$. But then $0 = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^k k^{-1} e_i \in \overline{\operatorname{conv}}(K_1)$.

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets Thanks!